# How to make recursive report in acumatica?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am generating crystal report in Acumatica, My report is little complex, our scenario is
Item 1 may have multiple items so we display like 
Level 1
    Item 1 
           Item 1- 1
           Item 1- 2
==============================================================
Level 2
Item 1- 1 may have also many item so want to display like
         Item 1-1- 1
          Item 1-1- 2
    Item 1- 2 may have also many item so want to display like
          Item 1-2- 1
          Item 1-2- 2
==============================================================
Level 3
    Item 1-1- 1 may have also many item so want to display like
          Item 1-1-1 - 1
          Item 1-1-1 - 2
    Item 1- 2 -2 may have also many item so want to display like
          Item 1-2-2 - 1
          Item 1-2-2 - 2
==============================================================
Continue....

it is ongoing process like a recursive call, what can be the best way to generate the report using Acumatica Report designer?

Comment: Nested subreports ?

Comment: Yes, we need nested report.

Comment: You should be able to create a report with what you need for one level, along with a subreport section where you reference the same report's name. Providing you allow the report a way to fail silently, you should be able to recurse as much as you need to.

Comment: As i shared example above, So we need recursion at multiple level, is that possible, If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like grouping. You might want to create group field that will give your the rendering order you want.  If that does not work for some reason, consider creating in-memory recordset (PXReportResultset, look for it in CashFlowEnq graph for example) that collects the records in the order you want and then use it to drive the report. Also, nested reports are not a good idea as it can impact rendering performance.